# Nginx + phpMyAdmin Issues

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm having an issue with my Nginx config file. When I load phpMyAdmin, everything works fine - except the images will not load.

Checking the error log, I see that all requests to images / other static content have "/index.php" added to the end of the request.

I would appreciate if someone could let me know what I am doing wrong.

Error Log:

```
2014/07/03 20:17:32 [error] 75683#0: *61 "/local/www/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/ajax_clock_small.gif/index.php" is not found
2014/07/03 20:17:33 [error] 75683#0: *59 "/local/www/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css/index.php" is not found
2014/07/03 20:17:33 [error] 75683#0: *61 "/local/www/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_left.png/index.php" is not found
2014/07/03 20:17:33 [error] 75683#0: *58 "/local/www/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/ajax_clock_small.gif/index.php" is not found
```

Nginx Config:

```
server {

    listen  XX.XX.XX.XXX:443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/cert/example.com/example.com.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/cert/example.com/example.com.key;

    server_name     example.com;
    access_log      off;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;

    root            /opt/www/example.com/httpdocs;
    index           index.php index.html;

    charset UTF-8;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;

    location  /phpmyadm/ {
       alias               /local/www/phpMyAdmin/;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadm/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|html|htm|txt|css|js))$ {
       alias              /local/www/phpMyAdmin/;
       expires            365d;
       etag               on;
    }

    # Pass off php requests to Apache
    location ~* \.php {
       include            /etc/nginx/proxypass.conf;
       proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80;
    }

    location @backend {
       include            /etc/nginx/proxypass.conf;
       proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Have you come across any fix lately?

Answer (score 1):

Create locatation like /phpmyadmin_secure for php and for assets like in this example

```
#### PHPMYADMIN
    location /phpmyadmin_secure {
        index index.php;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin_secure/(.+\.php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~ \.(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                root    /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
         }
    }
####
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `alias` instead of `root` and avoiding `try_files` worked great for me:

```
location ^~ /secure_phpmyadmin {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /secure_phpmyadmin/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Avoid `try_files` with `alias` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.